# How do you pass a POST method in a url manually?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, url-routing

I need to give an external payment site a return url to my site after a customer pays. It will be to my create action in a RESTful subscription controller.

Ive tried giving the payment site this

blah.com/users/7/subscription/?_method=POST

but on return my app keeps trying to call my show action presumably because it thinks its a get request and not a post. So somethings wrong with how i pass the method in the url but i cant figure out what.

Users are plural and they can only have one subscription which is defined in my routes as singular i.e. map.resource

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't POST from a GET request.

If the calling application is simply executing a URL this is a GET request.
If the payment site does not support POSTing back to you then you can't do it.

I would ask the payment site if they offer the ability to POST to you. Many do.

Answer (score 2):

If the external service isn't calling your url with a POST, then it is an issue with that service, not your application.  Also, keep in mind that CSRF will protect your POST, PUT, DELETE without a token, so you'll need to disable it for this method, and hopefully you have some other way of authenticating that request.